# Get logs for last 30 minutes

Tags: text-processing, awk, logs

I want to extract the logs between the current timestamp and 30 minutes before. I developed the below script but it's not working properly it shows only timestamp lines whereas I have to get untimestamped log lines in between such timestamped line. I have a log file containing this pattern:

script:

```
awk -v TSTART="$(date -v -30M "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")" -v TEND="$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")" '$0>=TSTART && $0<=TEND' webservice_logs.log
```

Log file pattern:

Answer (score 2):

You can print the lines based on a flag which is only set when the first field is a date field. see the following code with flag `p` to instruct awk to print (when `p==1`) or to skip (when `p==0`) the line

```
awk -v tstart="$start" -v tend="$end" '
    /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/ {
        t = $1 " " $2
        p = t >= tstart && t <= tend ? 1 : 0
    }p' webservice_logs.log
```

Since there is no timestamp at the beginning of ERROR lines, there is no flag change over such lines.

**Edit** On a single line:

```
awk -v tstart="$start" -v tend="$end" '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{t = $1 " " substr($2,1,5); p = t >= tstart && t <= tend ? 1 : 0}p' webservice_logs.log
```

Comment: This one is not working could you please help me with a one-liner. Above command is having spaces in between

Comment: @abhinavmahajan, updated.

Comment: Sorry this one is not helping

ThinkPad-E470:~$ awk -v tstart="$start" -v tend="$end" '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{t = $1 " " $2; p = t >= tstart && t <= tend ? 1 : 0}p' webservice_logs.log
ThinkPad-E470:~$

Comment: @abhinavmahajan what is the operating system? have you set up the variables `$start` and `$end` before running this awk command?

Comment: Yes they have been set

ThinkPad-E470:~$ echo $start 
2019-03-22 13:23
ThinkPad-E470:~$ 
ThinkPad-E470:~$ 
ThinkPad-E470:~$ echo $end
2019-03-23 04:48
ThinkPad-E470:~$ awk -v tstart="$start" -v tend="$end" '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{t = $1 " " $2; p = t >= tstart && t <= tend ? 1 : 0}p' webservice_logs.log
ThinkPad-E470:~$

Comment: @abhinavmahajan, what's your OS? what was the error you are having by running this code?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04 and it did not give any error, it just ran with an empty output.

Comment: @abhinavmahajan I adjusted the `t` to include only HH:MM instead of the full $2. please double check your data in log file and see if there is any date time fall between the date time range.

Comment: I tried new command which you edited, but the result is same.
Also I have checked for the start and end date in the log file which I am using

Comment: @abhinavmahajan, I modified the timestamp on your sample text to have logged datetime in between your specified start->end range and tested it under my Ubuntu 17.10 VM which works without any problem. Unless you can upload a snippet of the actual data, I don't think there is anything more I can do for you.

Comment: @abhinavmahajan, please also make sure the `$start` and `$end` are defined in the same terminal as when you run the awk command. I don't think this would be an issue for you though, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
awk -vStartDate=`date -d'now-30 min' +%H:%M:%S` '{ if ($2 > StartDate) print $0}' web.log
```

Comment: This one is not working

Comment: I have tested this on my machine with sample logs and it works.